# Distinct query with Id field

Tags: sql-server

In below table an Account can have multiple State value(I am not providing here the All address field except State field)

Note: Id field is of type varchar.

```html
Account           Id                 State
------------------      ------------------  ----------------
A1000                 1000                 MI
A1000                 1001              MI
A1001                 1002                 CA
A1001                 1003                 CA
A1002                 1004                 DE
A1002                 1005                 PS


I want to get output like below i.e. distinct of Account,State and its corresponding Top1 Id

 Account           Id                 State
------------------      ------------------  ----------------
A1000                 1000                 MI
A1001                 1002                 CA
A1002                 1004                 DE
A1002                 1005                 PS
```

Till now not able to form any query by myself. Can any one have any idea how to achieve this.

Comment: which type is the field ID?

Comment: @Galma88: Id is of varchar type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Account, [State] ORDER BY Id)
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT  Account,
        Id,
        [State]
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll get the smallest id like this:

```
select Account, min(Id) as Id, State
from yourtable
group by Account, State
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Account, MIN(Id), MIN(State)
FROM Account
GROUP BY Account
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query:

```
SELECT  T.Account,
        T.Id,
        T.[State]
FROM (

SELECT  *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Account, [State] ORDER BY Id)
    FROM dbo.YourTable ) AS T
WHERE T.RN = 1;
```